# C# store SQL Server date in LINQ date field like GETDATE() in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a query like this in a SQL Server stored procedure:

```
UPDATE StudentTable 
SET isUpdate = 1, updateDate = GETDATE()
```

I want its equivalent in Linq-to-entities inside C# so that `GETDATE()` be used. I don't want to use local client time and stuff like this. I want SQL Server time be the reference to be stored in the `updateDate` column

Comment: Do you mean using `DateTime.Now`?

Comment: Which EF version?

Answer (score 0):

These two options can help achieve your goal:

1. Using a raw SQL in Entity Framework
2. Calling a stored procedure with parameters

Let's see some code:

```
// your input from a secure source
int input = 1; 

// To add where and more lines you can use concatenation or string builder
string sql = $"UPDATE StudentTable SET isUpdate = {input}, 
updateDate = GETDATE()";

await db.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(sql);
```

**Note**: you could use parameters instead of string interpolation for security reasons.

Here's an example with stored procedure and parameters.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
//...

int input = 1;
long id = 10;

db.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("exec [schema].[myCustomSP] @isUpdate, @id", 
  new SqlParameter("isUpdate", input), 
  new SqlParameter("id", id));
```